# Optimize jQuery .find() selectors

Tags: jquery, optimization

## Question

Can we do this in one line ?

## Code

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$new.find('a.suppr').css('display', 'none');
$new.find('a.add').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Worth view/review: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ Doing so will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new.find('a.suppr,a.add').hide();
```

Comment: My bad, I tried something like that yesterday and it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the two selectors into one. You can also instead use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$new.find('a.suppr, a.add').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, seperate several selectors using a comma:

```
$new.find('a.suppr, a.add').css(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use it.

```
$new.find('a.suppr, a.add').css('display', 'none');
```

But if you want to apply different styles,

```
$new.find('a.suppr').css('color', 'red').end() // go back to $new
    .find('a.add').css('color', 'blue');
```